# AES-GCM 256 bit - Node.js encrypt / Android decrypt - 16 byte authentication tags don't match

Tags: android, node.js, authentication, aes-gcm

Trying to use AES-GCM 256 to encrypt "Hello World" in Node.js in such a way that the encrypted string sent ota to an Android phone can be decrypted.  The Node.js encryption code is:

```
const KEY = new Buffer('1bc0d563329d29fc6236f099371e334feb9bbf3e91bba2adb4043feb870b6b21', 'hex');
var iv = Buffer.from("0000000000000000",'base64');                         
var cipher = crypt.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', Buffer.from(KEY, 'utf-8'), iv);                   
var ciph = cipher.update(Buffer.from("Hello World", 'utf-8'), 'utf8', 'base64');  
ciphered += cipher.final('base64');
console.log(cipher.getAuthTag().toString('base64'));
```

and the Android (Studio) decryption code is:

```
public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] data)
            throws CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, UnrecoverableEntryException,
            KeyStoreException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        SecretKey secretKey = null;

        byte[] decodedKey = new byte[] {(byte)0x1b,(byte)0xc0,(byte)0xd5,(byte)0x63,(byte)0x32,(byte)0x9d,(byte)0x29,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x62,(byte)0x36,(byte)0xf0,(byte)0x99,(byte)0x37,(byte)0x1e,(byte)0x33,(byte)0x4f,(byte)0xeb,(byte)0x9b,(byte)0xbf,(byte)0x3e,(byte)0x91,(byte)0xbb,(byte)0xa2,(byte)0xad,(byte)0xb4,(byte)0x04,(byte)0x3f,(byte)0xeb,(byte)0x87,(byte)0x0b,(byte)0x6b,(byte)0x21};

        secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "AES");
        

        byte[] iv = Base64.decode("0000000000000000", Base64.DEFAULT);
        GCMParameterSpec gcmspec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM_NAME);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, gcmspec);
        return cipher.doFinal(data);
    }
```

which fails to decrypt because of authentication tag mismatch.  I verified the tags don't match by encrypting the same string in Android with the same key and initialization vector:

```
public void TEST_ENCRYPT() throws IOException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, UnrecoverableEntryException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchProviderException, BadPaddingException, KeyStoreException, IllegalBlockSizeException {

        String inputString = "Hello World";
        byte[] byteArray = inputString.getBytes();
        String value = Base64.encodeToString(encrypt(byteArray), Base64.DEFAULT);
        Log.d("TEST_ENCRYPT", value);
}

public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] data)
            throws CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, UnrecoverableEntryException,
            KeyStoreException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {

       
        SecretKey secretKey = null;

        byte[] decodedKey = new byte[] {(byte)0x1b,(byte)0xc0,(byte)0xd5,(byte)0x63,(byte)0x32,(byte)0x9d,(byte)0x29,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x62,(byte)0x36,(byte)0xf0,(byte)0x99,(byte)0x37,(byte)0x1e,(byte)0x33,(byte)0x4f,(byte)0xeb,(byte)0x9b,(byte)0xbf,(byte)0x3e,(byte)0x91,(byte)0xbb,(byte)0xa2,(byte)0xad,(byte)0xb4,(byte)0x04,(byte)0x3f,(byte)0xeb,(byte)0x87,(byte)0x0b,(byte)0x6b,(byte)0x21};

        secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM_NAME);
        
        byte[] iv = Base64.decode("0000000000000000", Base64.DEFAULT);
        GCMParameterSpec gcmspec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv);
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, gcmspec);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("error", e.toString());
        }
        return cipher.doFinal(data);
    }
```

and comparing the appended 16 bytes to the encrypted message (i.e. the Android authentication tag) to the Node.js authentication tag.  This authentication tag mismatch occurs despite the fact the encrypted messages are the same, and makes decryption of messages on the Android phone throw errors.  How can this problem be solved?  I would expect the AES-GCM 256 algorithm to work the same on both client and server.

Comment: To decrypt the ciphertext of the NodeJS code with the Android code, the key must be hex decoded in the NodeJS code, the `final()` call must be performed, and the ciphertext and tag must be concatenated.

Comment: In the NodeJS code, Base64 encoding must take place _after_ concatenation. Therefore it makes most sense to work with `Buffer`s: `var ciphertextTagB64 = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(Buffer.from("Hello World", 'utf-8')), cipher.final(), cipher.getAuthTag()]).toString('base64')`. This returns the ciphertext of the Android code. Conversely, the separation must not take place until after the Base64 decoding.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `Buffer`:

```js
new Buffer('1bc0d563329d29fc6236f099371e334feb9bbf3e91bba2adb4043feb870b6b21');
```

This is not what you expect, this is simply a string.

You need this:

```js
Buffer.from('1bc0d563329d29fc6236f099371e334feb9bbf3e91bba2adb4043feb870b6b21', 'hex');
```

Comment: Sorry, your comment and Topaco's comments are correct, but this is a mistake I made transcribing the code from a different computer. It actually reads: new Buffer('1bc0d563329d29fc6236f099371e334feb9bbf3e91bba2adb4043feb870b6b21', 'hex');, and there is a statement (ciphered += cipher.final('base64')) before the console.log output as you said there should be.

Comment: When I run the code in Node.js, I get the encrypted string 'kCi65IXrOPGBv/M', and the authentication tag 'ODm8KctJeobvjCfSvw8wiw' - same encrypted string in Android except the authentication tag is '4Obwpy0l6hu+MJ9K/DzCL'. Also tried this in swift using AES-GCM 256 in crypto kit and the output authentication tag matched the Node.js authentication tag

Comment: @DanielBrox - You should edit your question and correct the NodeJS code (a correction in the comment to an answer is not enough).

Comment: Corrected.  My mistake.

Comment: The problem appears to be caused by base64 encoding.  Fixed when I split the encrypted byte array before encoding to view the encrypted string and authentication tag separately:
      
        String valueBT = Base64.encodeToString(Arrays.copyOfRange(byteArrayEncrypt,0,byteArrayEncrypt.length-16), Base64.DEFAULT);
        String valueAT = Base64.encodeToString(Arrays.copyOfRange(byteArrayEncrypt,byteArrayEncrypt.length-16,byteArrayEncrypt.length), Base64.DEFAULT);